# Manage data source for multiple reports at once

Tags: reports

I have to change the shared datasource of multiple reports. Instead of managing the datasource per report, which is a tedious task, I'm looking for a way to add the string to multiple reports at once.

Is that possible!?

Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

Reports are just xml files.  So if you can figure out what XML to change in the files, then you could easily code something to change it for many files.  Or maybe just find a text editor which does find and replace for many files assuming all of the files are in the same document library.

Comment: Thnx Steve, I've found something like datasource id. I will be trying to replace that.